# Having an ERROR: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, appium

I'm new to coding. Currently, I am using Appium Java Eclipse.

Below is the error log.

```
  Nov 29, 2019 6:37:48 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
        at io.appium.java_client.internal.ElementMap.getElementClass(ElementMap.java:77)
        at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.newRemoteWebElement(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter.apply(JsonToWebElementConverter.java:55)
        at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.apply(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:61)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:61)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:151)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
        at DemoActualAutomation.main(DemoActualAutomation.java:15)
    Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

DemoActualAutomation.class:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class DemoActualAutomation extends AppiumDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = Capabilities();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Preference']").click();
    }

}
```

Am I missing something? Please help. Thank you!!

Comment: Is this when the program is built or when running in Eclipse ?

Comment: Is commons-lang3 jar file included in classpath?

Comment: It would be very helpful to see your code, where this error occurs.

Comment: Below r d codes I used

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class DemoActualAutomation extends AppiumDemo{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  
  AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=Capabilities();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Preference']").click();

Comment: - This is when running in Eclipse.
- I have commons-exec and commons-lang-2.6 on my Java Build Pat

Comment: I my goodness sorry my format is a mess!! I'm new here!

Answer (score 1):

- From the https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi
  Download the `commons-lang3-3.9-bin.zip`
- Extract locally
- In Eclipse Go to your Project Properties
- On the `Java Build Path` > `Libraries` Tab use the `Add External JARs`.
- Add the `Commons-lang3-3.9.jar` from the extracted folder.

Answer (score 1):

Download the commons-lang3-3.9-bin.zip

In Eclipse, Go to your Project >Rt. Click > Build Path >Configure Build Path >Add External Jars  >Select all 4 jars > Apply and Close.
ur code will run...

Answer (score 0):

`org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils` indicates you are using commons-lang3. You should add commons-lang3-xxx.jar to classpath. commons-lang-2.6 doesn't have `lang3` packages.